# Centroid tracking issue on Aforge C#

Tags: c#, tracking, aforge, centroid

I am creating a program that can track multiple objects and get their centroid eventually I would use these centroids to connect to the nearest centroid of another object. But my problem is, my program tracks only one significant object on the video and it doesn't seem to display the centroid of this object. anyone can help me?

```
namespace Video_Processing_fixed_
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Bitmap video;
        Graphics g;
        bool OnOff;
        int mode;
        int thoigiandemnguoc = 5;
        private FilterInfoCollection CaptureDevice;
        private VideoCaptureDevice FinalFrame;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CaptureDevice = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        foreach (FilterInfo Device in CaptureDevice)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(Device.Name);
        }
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        FinalFrame = new VideoCaptureDevice();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FinalFrame = new VideoCaptureDevice(CaptureDevice[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
        FinalFrame.NewFrame+=new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalFrame_NewFrame);
        FinalFrame.Start();
    }

        void FinalFrame_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            Bitmap video2 = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            g = Graphics.FromImage(video2);
            g.DrawString("Test", new Font("Arial", 20), new SolidBrush(Color.White), new PointF(2, 2));
            g.Dispose();
            if (mode == 1)
            {
                // create filter
                EuclideanColorFiltering filter = new EuclideanColorFiltering();
                // set center colol and radius
                filter.CenterColor = Color.FromArgb(215, 30, 30);
                filter.Radius = 100;
                // apply the filter
                filter.ApplyInPlace(video2);


                BlobCounter blobcounter = new BlobCounter();
                blobcounter.MinWidth = 5;
                blobcounter.MinHeight = 5;
                blobcounter.FilterBlobs = true;
                blobcounter.ObjectsOrder = ObjectsOrder.Area;
                blobcounter.ProcessImage(video2);
                Blob[] blobs = blobcounter.GetObjectsInformation();
                AForge.Point Center = new AForge.Point();

                   if (blobs.Length > 0)
                     {
                        Center.X = blobs.Average(c => c.CenterOfGravity.X);
                        Center.Y = blobs.Average(c => c.CenterOfGravity.Y);
                     }

               Rectangle[] rects = blobcounter.GetObjectsRectangles();
                foreach(Rectangle recs in rects)
                if (rects.Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (Rectangle objectRect in rects)
                    {
                        Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(video2);
                        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(160, 255, 160), 5))
                        {
                            graphic.DrawRectangle(pen, objectRect);
                        }

                        graphic.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
               ( Pen pen = new Pen(Color.White,3))

            pictureBox2.Image = video2;
            pictureBox1.Image = video;
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (FinalFrame.IsRunning==true)
            {

                FinalFrame.SignalToStop();
                FinalFrame.WaitForStop();
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox2.Image = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image.Clone();
        }

        private void ButObjTrack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mode = 1;
        }

        private void StopButt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FinalFrame.SignalToStop();

        }

}
```

}

Comment: Your program is deficient and is full of syntax errors. I managed to get it work, and I dont see any problem. It finds all the pinkish objects I show the camera. The centroid isn't displayed because you dont display it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not display the average center value. Change these lines:

```
Rectangle[] rects = blobcounter.GetObjectsRectangles();
foreach(Rectangle recs in rects)
    if (rects.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (Rectangle objectRect in rects)
        {
            Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(video2);
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(160, 255, 160), 5))
            {
                graphic.DrawRectangle(pen, objectRect);
            }
            graphic.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

To these:

```
Rectangle[] rects = blobcounter.GetObjectsRectangles();
foreach (Rectangle recs in rects)
{
    if (rects.Length > 0)
    {
        Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(video2);
        foreach (Rectangle objectRect in rects)
        {
            graphic.DrawRectangle(Pens.LightGreen, objectRect);

        }
        graphic.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, Center.X - 4, Center.Y - 4, 8, 8);
        graphic.Dispose();
    }
}
```